# Error when run maven webapp in Intellij idea ultimate2017.2: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I import an exist maven project into Intellij idea ultimate2017.2, and add a tomcat local server, but when i run the project, error happens:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/slf4j/Logger;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:64)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
```

I'm using `tomcat8.5.16`,`maven3.5.0`,and the `slf4j` dependency in `pom.xml` is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Will intellij automatically add the maven dependency into web lib? I can't find the `lib` directory in `webapp/WEB_INF`, and how to add the maven libs into webapp?

Comment: Try reimporting the project, IntelliJ IDEA will generate the artifacts automatically with all the libraries, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html.

Answer (score 0):

Should use mvn command to build the project. Open `Run/Debug Configuration` ->Select you created `Tomcat Server`->`Before launch:Maven Goal,Build Artifacts,Activate tool window` -> click `+` and use `maven clean package`